# Salesforce 1 - Android

Tags: salesforce1-app

Good morning,

I would like to know which is the lower Salesforce 1 supported by Android?

Best Regards.

Comment: are you asking for the compatible versions of Salesforce1 app that can run in Android ? which version of android you are after ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have, at least, Android 4.2 (Jelly Bean), otherwise you just get Chatter Mobile which is not the Salesforce1 Mobile app.

From the [Google Play Store listing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.salesforce.chatter&hl=en):

> The latest version of Salesforce1 requires devices with Android OS 4.2 (Jelly Bean) or later. Devices with Android OS 4.1 or earlier will receive Chatter Mobile 3.4